# Design for microservice servicing both async batch and sync UI requests

Tags: asynchronous, request, response, batch-processing, microservices

We have a microservice (written in Java) whose purpose is to validate requests according to a various sets of business rules, and return the results back to the source system.  We are running this on AWS in a docker container on an ECS cluster.

It is currently implemented for batch requests where

1. Batch system publishes an SNS message on a topic.
2. The SNS subscriber posts message into the microservice's SQS queue
3. Microservice processes the request
4. Microservice publishes a message on another topic with the response
5. The SNS subscriber posts the response to the batch systems's SQS queue
6. Batch system processes the response

We now have a use case for a UI to reuse the logic in this microservice.  In this case, the UI should receive the response immediately and display the results to the user.  If the UI posts a message to the microservice's SQS queue (via API Gateway), we can't guarantee a timely response as there may be a lot of messages in the queue from the batch system.  Should we create another microservice for the UI requests or is there another way?

Comment: Your microservice is `SQS -> process -> SQS`. Why not expose an API for the process? `HTTP request -> process -> HTTP response`.

Comment: Is this good practice from an infrastructure point of view?  If the both the batch and api are running in the same docker container we would risk the batch process taking up all the resource which would affect the performance of the UI

Comment: Then it depends(tm) on how you're implementing your queue reader. Is it single-threaded? Multi-threaded with a fixed thread pool? It also depends(tm) on what your requirements are for the UI requests - how many are you going to have? What's the perc95 of requests / sec in comparison to the batch requests? Etc etc.

Comment: We are running the process on an ECS cluster which is set to autoscale up to 5 instances i.e. we have a max of 5 requests being processed at the same time (we can increase this if we need to).  The problem with autoscaling on AWS is that it is not instant.  It can take anything up to 15 mins to scale up which is not acceptable for a UI response.  The UI requests will come from external users.  We do not at this stage have an indication of the volumes from the UI but they will be significantly lower than the batch and they will be sporadic.

Comment: We expect the batch volumes to get higher over time and we would like to be able to process batch throughout the day while still being able to service the UI.  Suggestions on what are options are would be much appreciated

Comment: Ah; then I'd suggest either a dedicated instance, or AWS Lambda.

Comment: Great - that's what I suspected.  Thanks for your all your input.